# New version instead of internationalizing?

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, internationalization

My client have asked me to translate my app to english.

They want an english version of the current app. They wanna release it at a different price tier internationally..

Would apple approve a separate version, or do i have to internationalize the current app?

Comment: Don't go flooding the store with fluff. Tell your client that if he wants a higher price, then to raise the price of a localized app.

Comment: @jer, since that is not how the free market works, the client may not appreciate being told how to price apps.

Comment: The client may not also appreciate apple pulling them from the dev program over polluting the store with similar apps. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for it to be at a different price tier, iTunesConnect is going to need a separate app upload.  That doesn't mean that it can't be the same app, but with different resources, icon, name, etc.

You could make separate targets in the same app that bundle up the different versions.  The same project could be used to generate them.

Comment: You'll have to read Apple's terms to know for sure whether this is ok -- I am only commenting on how to go about it in an efficient way